# Will changing my harddrive to a SSD void my MBP 2011 warranty?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I want to upgrade my harddrive to a SSD. Does apple offer this service? I was going to do it myself, since its easy. Does this void my warranty?

Comment: The "void your warranty" meme is very simplistic for something that has different interpretations around the world. Rather than hope the answerer here is in the same place as you, call up Apple if you ever have questions about what the warranty covers for your specific situation. Don't rely on armchair advice / general or past experience for what is legal if you can get an answer from the company that will be providing the service you seek.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it will not void your warranty. If you refer to the [top of these instructions](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/MacBook_Pro_17inch_Mid2010_Hard_Drive_DIY.pdf), they clearly state only a deviation of the steps outlined may void your warranty:

> Follow the instructions in this document carefully. Failure to follow
>   these instructions could damage your equipment and void its warranty.
>   Online instructions are available at
>   http://www.apple.com/support/diy/

Typically, anything that is printed in the owner's manual is covered under warranty. RAM and changing the hard drive are both topics that are carefully covered, so legally speaking, that means they are user serviceable. Anything user serviceable is covered under warranty (following the above proviso of course).

Unless it explicitly states in the manual that such modifications must be performed by a qualified technician, you will not be in breach of your warranty.

Comment: Use care - it's not who does the repair that matters - it's whether they cause physical or other damage. Qualified techs know when they break things and fix them for you as part of the service. As long as you don't break things, you're in the clear. Do be aware, you limit your service options if you bring in a mac with parts that aren't to apple's specs. Keep your old hard drive so you can put it in should you need a future repair.

Comment: @bmike *"it's not who does the repair that matters - it's whether they cause physical or other damage."* I'm sorry, but that's not the case. You cannot replace, say, a faulty heatsink in a Mac mini without voiding the warranty. It matters not if you "break" something or install the new part properly. The moment you open the unit, your warranty is void. It doesn't boil down to "damage" or even technical ability, it boils down to legality. Authorized techs have their repairs "sanctioned" by law, so anything they do, is covered within the warranty. You don't gain these privileges I'm afraid.

Comment: I stand by my "don't break things/put all apple parts back in before asking for Service". Your heat sink example is a straw man argument dodging the issue. Apple at its sole discretion determines whether to perform warranty service - they go from observable damage and unauthorized parts - not from legal filings or theory. I think perhaps you are over generalizing - we're talking a user replaceable commodity part - not major surgery here. If you break your mac - you pay to fix it. If if fails under "normal" use - apple pays. Routine HD swaps are normal use per the Apple manual for MBP 2011.

Comment: "Routine HD swaps are normal use per the Apple manual for MBP 2011". Yes, that's what I said above. This only applies to things *expressly* covered in your manual, not *everything* in the machine. "they go from observable damage and unauthorized parts" No, they do not. Walk into an Apple Store and tell them you re-applied thermal paste on your heatsinks and ask them to service the machine. Whether there are signs of physical damage or not, they will refuse work citing that you voided your warranty by committing such an act. Call them and ask. You are wrong. I see no further need to argue this.

Comment: Apple told me something different. I bought AppleCare coverate ten days ago for my MacBook Pro (early 2011). I had already installed a 240G OWC Mercury SSD, when I called for support to get help installing bootcamp, I explained my configuration, and they said "We are sorry, you have voided your warranty, your AppleCare support is terminated." Apple is sending me a refund on my AppleCare purchase - so basically I got ten days of support for free. But had I known this, I would have bought the Apple SSD instead.

Comment: @Dan They misspoke. If the replacement of the hardware is documented in the owner's manual, then it falls under the product warranty. Only a deviation from the steps that invariably leads to damage is not covered. But that is outside of the AppleCare coverage, which only covers Apple products and direct Apple hardware. You would have retained the AC coverage would you have bought an Apple SSD. They cut you off because you purchased a 3rd party component, something which (understandably) Apple doesn't cover. You didn't void your machine's warranty, just breeched the AC agreement.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.macsales.com/18244-owc-diys-wont-void-your-macs-warranty

The link above states the following:

*"We address this topic directly with customers via our support portals and are happy to inform you here of the same fact: upgrading your Mac does not void its warranty.
This consumer protection is owed to the little known Magnuson-Moss Warranty Act of 1975. Put simply, the act states that a company can’t require you to upgrade with only its own branded parts to retain the warranty. This important act protects your rights as a consumer and allows you to install OWC upgrades with peace of mind confidence."*